# Who is parentmost entity in JS (Object or Function)?

Tags: javascript

[image: Image is taken from Kyle simpson book this and Object prototypes]

**According to image (Image is taken from Kyle simpson book this and Object prototypes)**

1. Every function prototype has a prototype that is linked (or inheritin using Prototypical inheritance) to Object.prototype.
2. Object.prototype has a property i.e constructor that points Object.
3. Object even has a prototype property (that means it is also inheriting from Function’s prototype).
4. Function prototype has a constructor property that points to Function.

I don’t understand who is parent most **Object** or **Function**.
According to image **Function** is parentmost.

Comment: You're confusing `prototype` properties on functions and the `[[Prototype]]` of a function (for instance, in #3 in your list). They're different things.

Comment: The topmost "object" that really *every* object inherits from is `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "parentmost" I'm going to assume you're asking: What's the topmost thing in this image? The thing that everything else derives from? E.g., a "root" object.

The closest thing to a root object in that image is the object that `Object.prototype` points to, in the upper right-hand corner. That's the root object of the inheritance hierarchy shown in that image.

That object is the prototype of `Function.prototype`, which is the function object that is used as the prototype of all other functions by default, including the `Function` function, the `Object` function, etc. (It's possible to have functions with other prototypes — derived `class` constructors are one example — or even no prototype, but by default a function has `Function.prototype` as its prototype.)

Addressing your list:

> 1. Every function prototype has a prototype that is linked (or inheritin using Prototypical inheritance) to Object.prototype.

By "Every function prototype" I think you mean "the object on the `prototype` property of every function." That's true *by default* for functions that have a `prototype` property (not all do; arrow functions don't, for instance), but `prototype` is just a property, it can be changed.

> 2. Object.prototype has a property i.e constructor that points Object.

That's true, but it's not really relevant. *(More below.)*

> 3. Object even has a prototype property (that means it is also inheriting from Function’s prototype).

The fact `Object` has a `prototype` property doesn't have anything to do with it inheriting from `Function`'s prototype. It has to do with the way the `Object` function is defined in the specification, which says that it has a `prototype` property that refers to the root object prototype.

> 4. Function prototype has a constructor property that points to Function.

That's true but also not really relevant.

The `constructor` property on the objects referred to by the `prototype` property of functions is very rarely used by JavaScript itself. (It wasn't used **at all** until ES2015.) It's not involved in the workings of inheritance, for instance. Since ES2015 it's been used in a few places to create new objects of the same subclass as other objects, for instance when `Array.prototype.slice` creates a new array, it uses the `constructor` property of the source array to create the new array.